# Regular expressions in Sphider PHP search engine

Tags: php, regex, url, sphider

I try to implement a Sphider websearch in my site and start indexing. There are 2 opinions: URL must include / URL must not include. I have to use regular expressions and want to index a site that I know the link structure and I want to crawl all URLs that includes `http://example.com/frage/....`

When I put in the regex field `*/frage/` it won't work because access to index is forbidden. I also tried `*\/frage` and `*\/frage\/`.

How can I handle that?

Comment: please, add some code

Comment: here you will find the tutorial. its all about writing a regular expression into a textarea http://www.sphider.eu/docs.php#mustinc my problem is when i just want to index some subpages, access to index is forbidden so i need a regex to crawl domain without anything or the subdirectory /frage

Comment: @Sasa so you know the specific expression i am looking for? i want to include only the index.php and a specific single virtual subdirectory.

Comment: Do you intend to query the web server using a regex?

Comment: i think thats the way its gone to be. i have to put it into a textarea before indexing. there is a textarea named "url must include" and another one "url must not include" and theres a hint "you have to use regular expressions"

Comment: Any url containing a string in the 'must not include' list is ignored. Any url that does not contain any string in the 'must include' list is likewise ignored. All strings in the string list should be separated by a newline (enter). For example, to prevent a forum in your site from being indexed, you might add www.yoursite.com/forum to the "must not include" list. Using Perl style regular expressions instead of literal strings is also supported. Every string starting with a '*' in front is considered as a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is looking for a solution i came up with that:

```
/example.com(\/?)($|frage)/
```